Wrong Key Code detected in JavaScript (KeyZ instead of KeyY when Y is pressed)
I'm encountering an issue with keyboard events in JavaScript. When I press the ctrl+shift+y key combination, the event.key property correctly reports Y, but the event.code property incorrectly reports KeyZ. This is unexpected because the physical key being pressed is Y, not Z. This also happens when I just press Y without ctrl/shift.
Here is the test code I'm using:
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log('Key:', event.key);        // Character produced by the key
    console.log('Code:', event.code);      // Physical key on the keyboard
    console.log('Ctrl:', event.ctrlKey);   // Boolean for Ctrl key
    console.log('Shift:', event.shiftKey); // Boolean for Shift key
});


Browser: Chrome, Firefox, Edge
Operating System: Windows

I also tested it on this page
When I press ctrl+shift+y, I get the following output:
Key: Y
Code: KeyZ
Ctrl: true
Shift: true

Expected output:
Key: Y
Code: KeyY
Ctrl: true
Shift: true


Not reproducible. Change browsers and test. Did you do any kinds of customization in browser settings

Do you have a German keyboard layout where Z and Y are swapped?

Depending on your keyboard layout the results may vary. If your layout is set to german (for example) in your OS, the returned values for some keycodes (number in event.which) are changed.

Y becomes Z
Z becomes Y
semicolon becomes ö
...and so on.

The positions of the keys don't change and the informations (numbers) sent by the keyboard to the pc are always the same. (event.which)
The operating system translates these numbers to the symbols that are presented on the layout of the keyboard-layout you use. Some return values (like the event.code) are there for backwards compatibility with older applications.
event.code just returns fixed values represented by the english layout.
From MDN:

KeyboardEvent: code property
The KeyboardEvent.code property represents a physical key on the keyboard (as opposed to the character generated by pressing the key). In other words, this property returns a value that isn't altered by keyboard layout or the state of the modifier keys.

Source: KeyboardEvent:Code
